# How to control character encoding in Spring integration TCP gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have set up a Spring integration gateway using the documentation and examples that are available online. I'm sending an XML message that is ISO-8859-1 encoded, but the receiving part is telling me that the message comes to them in an encoding different from ISO-8859-1.

My config looks like this:

```
    <!-- Spring integration begins -->
<beans:bean id="javaDeserializer"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayRawSerializer" />

<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="com.pawsec.alarmcenter.model.SOSAccessV4.SimpleGateway"
    default-request-channel="input"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="cfClient"
    type="client"
    host="${rapid.alarm.ipaddress}"
    port="${rapid.alarm.port}"
    deserializer="javaDeserializer"
    single-use="true"
    so-timeout="10000"/>

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="input"
    reply-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"
    connection-factory="cfClient"
    request-timeout="10000"/>

<int:channel id="clientBytes2StringChannel"/>

<int:object-to-string-transformer id="clientBytes2String"
    input-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel" />

 <!-- Spring integration ends -->
```

I need to know how i can control the character encoding of the outgoing stream. Also - is there any way i can check the outgoing message myself without having to call the receiving party and ask him to check?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The `TcpNetConnection` uses `TcpMessageMapper` for converting message to the `byte[]` before sending:

```
Object object = this.getMapper().fromMessage(message);
```

Where its code looks like (by default, of course):

```
bytes = ((String) payload).getBytes(this.charset);
```

Where it is like:

```
private volatile String charset = "UTF-8";
```

So, you should provide your `mapper` with desired `charset` to convert `ISO-8859-1` XML to bytes.

Re.

> check the outgoing message myself

You can use some TCP Trace tool, like wire Wireshark to proxy and intercept the traffic.

Comment: Thank you Artem. I will try this tomorrow morning.

Comment: i don't understand the relation between a TcpNetConnection and the TcpServerConnectionFactory that i get from this configuration. Is there such a relation or do i have to configure one? @artem bilan

Comment: `TcpNetConnection` is a product of `TcpServerConnectionFactory`, as it sounds by the `Factory` pattern. Of course I meant `mapper` option on the `<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory>` component.

Comment: I spent a big chunk of the day on this. Figuring out where the mapper fits in wasn't all that difficult and configuring the Factory for ISO-8859-1 was simple. However, using the sample annotation-based configuration turned out to be a bit tricky. I used the code at the bottom of this page: [http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors]

Comment: Well, that is `MessageChannel` bean which should be obvious for documentation by the `defaultRequestChannel` attribute name.

Comment: Yes, that bean is not included in the documented config class. Is it supposed to be created automatically? When i added it to the config file, it solved the issue.

Comment: It is created automatically and in recent releases we have fixed several bugs around "late binding". From other side it is *documentation*, so we aren't intended to place there all the beans. I'm glad that you figured out and fixed the issue, so let's close the question and go to work!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the original issue by configuring the client factory with a mapper for ISO-8859-1 like this:

```
        @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientCF() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(HOST, PORT);
        TcpMessageMapper tcpMessageMapper = new TcpMessageMapper();
        logger.debug("Setting deserializer");
        clientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());
        tcpMessageMapper.setCharset("ISO-8859-1");
        logger.debug("setting mapper!");
        clientConnectionFactory.setMapper(tcpMessageMapper);
        return clientConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Tell me what i'm supposed to do and i'll do it. I used your help to solve my issue and i thought i was supposed to share the solution upon closing the issue. I don't spend my life on Stack Exchange, so i'm not familiar with all rules and etiquette. I did not come here to plagiarize.  I needed help to solve a problem.

Comment: OK. Never mind then. I suppose it just would be good to *accept* the answer and we're fine here.

Comment: My intention with closing this issue with a solid description of the solution was that the next guy with the same issue could use it and solve it for himself in no time at all. Isn't that how we operate here? Your accusation of plagiarism makes no sense to me. I will not waste any more time explaining myself.